# A web button (mysite) send message to android notifycation (like Broadcastreceiver)

Tags: android, button, web, message

Is it possible to receive a message on my android - when I push a button on my webpage.

I have been looking at a Broadcastreceiver, would it be the correct way, if it is possible.

Before I walk you through a long story about my thought, please tell me it this possible at all.

Comment: I think you can accomplish this using GCM. That means you have to register the device before though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to send notifications from a website to an android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13724007/how-to-send-notifications-from-a-website-to-an-android-app)

Comment: Is the webpage in the Android, or is there another computer involved, if so, what have you attempted so far? Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it was a good way to ask a question, before I involved you to much. I have been looking at GCM, looks like it is possible so I will proberly go for that, thanks for you time.